# Como meter moment.js en una aplicación Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs

Quiero meter la librería de Moment.js en una aplicación Vue, y que esté disponible la funcionalidad completa de *moment* en cualquier componente de mi app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para 'instalar' [moment.js](https://momentjs.com) en tu app Vue hacemos lo siguiente:

```
// main.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import moment from 'moment'
import App from './App'
...

Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$moment', {value: moment})
```

Con esto ya tenemos acceso a moment en nuestros componentes de esta forma:
`this.$moment()`

Ejemplo, en nuestro fichero App.vue

```
const date = "21/01/2018"
const format = "DD/MM/YYYY"
this.$moment(date, format).isValid()
```

**Edit**:
Como dice Pablo en el comentario de abajo, esto se puede usar con otras librerías, por ejemplo [lodash](https://lodash.com/)

Comment: Si pensabas autoresponderte desde el inicio, creo que podrías generalizar la pregunta/respuesta a *Cómo meter una librería de utilidades en Vue*, ya que podrías hacer esto mismo con lodash (por ejemplo) ;)

Comment: Tienes toda la razón. Lo mismo vale para lodash